# Анимация сразу после загрузки страницы

Tags: css

Есть такая проблема что при загрузке документа все элемент к которым присвоен :hover и transition анимируются сразу после загрузки страницы при этом я никаких манипуляций не проводил! Как исправить?

```
a {text-decoration: none; color: #ffaf25; transition: color .5s;}
a:hover {color: #424242;}
```

Comment: hover - это псевдо-класс, его нельзя присвоить; элемент привязывается к такому псевдоклассу, когда указатель находится над элементом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если добавить любой элемент "a", то анимация происходит при наведении, как и задано в стиле. Думаю ошибка где-то в другом месте

HTML

```
<a>link_text</a>
```

CSS

```
a {text-decoration: none; color: #ffaf25; transition: color .5s;}
a:hover {color: #424242;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ehb8gq9/1/